# How do I make Prettier format my code with indentation continuation?

Tags: javascript, prettier

If we are to follow Google JavaScript Style guide, then according to this:

https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#formatting-indent

when wrapping long lines, "each line after the first (each continuation line) is indented at least +4 from the original line"

For example,

```
const v = 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + ... // goes beyond line limit
```

Google JavaScript Style suggests, we line wrap like:

```
const v =
    10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + ...
```

See full example: https://github.com/saad-learns/prettier-example/blob/main/bar.js

But with prettier, we get

```
const v =
  10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + ...
```

See full example: https://github.com/saad-learns/prettier-example/blob/main/foo.js

I am not able to find a way to make Prettier follow Google JavaScript Style. Is there no option? or is Prettier's philosophy not compatible with Google's JavaScript Style?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no option for that. And Google style seems inconsistent to me, using 2 spaces in one place but 4 (or more) in others.

Comment: If I understand it right then and you first to be 2 spaces, second and more to be 4, I am almost sure there is no option to do that in default prettier and don't know about any extensions to do this. Most people use: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript which prettier works nicely with.

Comment: @MalwareMoon FYI, IDEs like IntelliJ do provide that option see: https://github.com/saad-learns/prettier-example/blob/main/images/intellij_continuation.png

Comment: @Bergi not sure I agree it's inconsistent :) . The style makes a distinction  in continuation indent vs block indent. `if/while/function etc...` introduces block, therefore 2 spaces, but continuation line does not introduce a block, therefore it's indented differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this has been asked by someone else in prettier github issue:

https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/11897

and the answer is they won't add any more options to support line continuation  differently than block indent.